# General Protection Fault inside boot code with wrmsr instruction inside KVM

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, boot, osdev

I am trying to boot processor into long mode using KVM. I have been able to setup small KVM Hypervisor derived and built upon [this lwn example](https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/).

Now, Iam trying to boot the processor to long mode. So far, the sequence I have followed is.

1. Using KVM, initialize first eip to be 0x1000, from where my code starts instead of reset state.
2. Load GDT, do a long jump to 32 bit trampoline code.
3. In the Trampoline, Enable PAE, PSE in cr4. Load page director address in cr3, followed by setting LM bit in cr4. Setting LM bit generate general protection fault(verified through setting UP IDT and then seeing the trap handler invoked)

My code is:

```
__reset: // 0x1000 
        cli                                                                                                
        mov     $gdtr, %eax
        lgdt    (%eax)
        movl    %cr0, %eax
        orl     $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, %cr0
        jmp $0x08, $trampoline
trampoline:
        movl    $STACK_START, %esp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        // Set up the protected-mode data segment registers                                                                                                  
        movl    $0x10, %eax    // Our data segment selector                                                                                                  
        movl    %eax, %ds      // -> DS: Data Segment                                                                                                        
        movl    %eax, %es      // -> ES: Extra Segment                                                                                                       
        movl    %eax, %ss      // -> SS: Stack Segment                                                                                                       
        movl    $0, %eax       // Zero segments not ready for use                                                                                            
        movl    %eax, %fs      // -> FS                                                                                                                      
        movl    %eax, %gs      // -> GS                                                                                                                      
        call    fill_idt
        movl    $idt_descriptor, %eax
        lidtl   (%eax)
        // 9.8.5 Initializing IA-32e Mode, pg 3153 intel-manual                                                                                              
        // step-1 disable cr0.paging                                                                                                                         
        // it is disabled already right now                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        // step-2 enable PAE.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        movl %cr4, %eax
        orl $(CR4_PAE | CR4_PSE), %eax
        movl %eax, %cr4
        // step-3 set cr2 to level-4 or level-5                                                                                                              
        // set cr3 to a pointer to pml4                                                                                                                      
        movl $boot_p4, %eax
        movl %eax, %cr3
        // step-4 efer.lme = 1                                                                                                                               
        // enable long mode and the NX bit                                                                                                                   
        movl $MSR_EFER, %ecx
        rdmsr
        orl $(EFER_LM | EFER_NX | EFER_SCE), %eax                                                                                                                                             
        wrmsr // <------ IT FAULTS HERE. GENERAL PROTECTION FAULT

.p2align 4
NULL_DESC:
        .quad 0x0000000000000000

CODE_DESC:
        .word 0xFFFF       // limit low                                                                                                                      
        .word 0            // base low                                                                                                                       
        .byte 0            // base middle                                                                                                                    
        .byte 0b10011010    // access                                                                                                                        
        .byte 0b11001111    // granularity                                                                                                                   
        .byte 0            // base high                                                                                                                      

DATA_DESC:
        .word 0xFFFF       // data descriptor                                                                                                                
        .word 0            // limit low                                                                                                                      
        .byte 0            // base low                                                                                                                       
        .byte 0b10010010    // access                                                                                                                        
        .byte 0b11001111    // granularity                                                                                                                   
        .byte 0            // base high                                                                                                                      
gdtr:
        .word gdtr - NULL_DESC - 1
        .long NULL_DESC
```

My register states before `wrmsr` instruction is

```
rip    = 0x000000000000189e // hlt instruction added just before wrmsr
rax    = 0x0000000000000901
rbx    = 0x00000000000020e0
rcx    = 0x00000000c0000080
rdx    = 0x0000000000000000
rsp    = 0x000000000000b000
rbp    = 0x000000000000b000
rdi    = 0x000000000000a000
rsi    = 0x0000000000000000
rflags = 0x0000000000000002
efer   = 0x0000000000000000
cr0    = 0x0000000060000011
cr2    = 0x0000000000000000
cr3    = 0x0000000000003000
cr4    = 0x0000000000000030
```

As per Intel Manual section "9.8.5 Initializing IA-32e Mode"
64-bit mode consistency checks fail in the following circumstances:

1. An attempt is made to enable or disable IA-32e mode while paging is enabled.
2. IA-32e mode is enabled and an attempt is made to enable paging prior to enabling physical-address extensions (PAE).
3. IA-32e mode is active and an attempt is made to disable physical-address extensions (PAE).
4. If the current CS has the L-bit set on an attempt to activate IA-32e mode.
5. If the TR contains a 16-bit TSS on an attempt to activate IA-32e mode.

All first 4 conditions are met. I do not undersrand 5 point, and I dont think I have any TSS segment set.

Why this instruction is cauing General Protection Fault?

Comment: Just an FYI, it's a lot easier to jump directly from real mode to long mode (procedure on [OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Entering_Long_Mode_Directly)). I use it, and it's worked on every virtual and physical machine I've tried. It also makes your GDT simpler because most of the flags are ignored in long mode.

Comment: Also, you don't need to set `CR4.PSE` - it's ignored in long mode.

Comment: @sj95126, yeah cr4.pse is indeed not required, I know that. Just the reference I was following was enabling it, so was just giving a try. I will try jumping to long mode from real mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

So after days of trying, I tried to see if long mode is supported via cpuid instruction, and apparantly the cpuid instruction returns zero.

So, the output of cpuid instruction has to be set via KVM_SET_CPUID2 ioctl.

The procedure I followed was to first fetch the current list of cpuid functions from host using KVM_GET_SUPPORTED_CPUID and then setting the returns structure using KVM_SET_CPUID2 ioctl. Following code snipped did the trick. It seems, setting what cpuid instruction should return on guest also enables the features.

```
nent = 128;
cpuid2 =
(struct kvm_cpuid2 *)
    malloc(sizeof(struct kvm_cpuid2)
           + nent * sizeof(struct kvm_cpuid_entry2));
cpuid2->nent = nent;
if(ioctl(kvm, KVM_GET_SUPPORTED_CPUID, cpuid2) < 0)
    fatal("cant get cpuid");

print_cpuid_output(cpuid2);

vm->vcpufd = ioctl(vm->fd, KVM_CREATE_VCPU, (unsigned long)0);
if(vm->vcpufd == -1)
    fatal("Cannot create vcpu\n");

if(ioctl(vm->vcpufd, KVM_SET_CPUID2, cpuid2) < 0)
    fatal("cannot set cpuid things\n");
```